# How to insert mini calendar image by url

Tags: web-services, calendar

I'd like to put a mini calendar of the current month and next month into a document. I can insert images by url into most document programs, so I was hoping to find a free service out there that serves up images of mini month calendars. The idea being I would never have to worry about changing the calendar image, no matter when I print the document in the future.

Is there any services out there that can provide a basic image?

If it isn't clear what type of calendar I'm looking for, I just need an "at-a-glance" month, just like *one of the months* shown in this image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use bootstrap, you could give this a shot: http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/

Here's another one that just uses jQuery:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Full-Year-Calendar-Generator-jQuery/

You wouldn't have to worry about a third party service going down, since the calendar code would all be hosted on your own site.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm looking to get ONE or TWO months at a time instead of a full year of months. It appears I may be able to get the calendar to show that, then if I can make an image of the page to provide with a url, it would be accomplished.